# Compiling a Go program with C Libraries into a Standalone executable

Tags: compilation, go, linker

I'm trying to compile a go program to be completely standalone including the c libraries. The command I'm using is

```
[mm17@mm17 grogger]$ go build --ldflags '-extldflags "-static"' ./grogger.go
# command-line-arguments
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgrok
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
/home/mm17/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/6l: running gcc failed: unsuccessful exit status 0x100
```

So I'll modify the file that calls the grok library to have the following header

```
  1 package grok
  2
  3 /*
  4 #cgo LDFLAGS: -L /usr/lib/libgrok.so -lgrok
  5 #include <grok.h>
  6 */
  7 import "C"
```

And then running the same command gives

```
[mm17@mm17 grogger]$ go build --ldflags '-extldflags "-static"' ./grogger.go
# github.com/blakesmith/go-grok
/usr/bin/ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000000400180
/tmp/go-build731085030/github.com/blakesmith/go-grok/_obj/grok.cgo2.o: In function `_cgo_4244208c3352_Cfunc_strlen':
../../blakesmith/go-grok/grok.go:169: undefined reference to `strlen'
/tmp/go-build731085030/github.com/blakesmith/go-grok/_obj/grok.cgo2.o: In function `_cgo_4244208c3352_Cfunc_grok_patterns_import_from_file':
../../blakesmith/go-grok/grok.go:159: undefined reference to `grok_patterns_import_from_file'
/tmp/go-build731085030/github.com/blakesmith/go-grok/_obj/grok.cgo2.o: In function `_cgo_4244208c3352_Cfunc_grok_pattern_add':
../../blakesmith/go-grok/grok.go:147: undefined reference to `grok_pattern_add'
/tmp/go-build731085030/github.com/blakesmith/go-grok/_obj/grok.cgo2.o: In function `_cgo_4244208c3352_Cfunc_grok_new':
../../blakesmith/go-grok/grok.go:132: undefined reference to `grok_new'
/tmp/go-build731085030/github.com/blakesmith/go-grok/_obj/grok.cgo2.o: In function `_cgo_4244208c3352_Cfunc_grok_match_walk_next':
../../blakesmith/go-grok/grok.go:123: undefined reference to `grok_match_walk_next'
/tmp/go-build731085030/github.com/blakesmith/go-grok/_obj/grok.cgo2.o: In function `_cgo_4244208c3352_Cfunc_grok_exec':
../../blakesmith/go-grok/grok.go:81: undefined reference to `grok_exec'
/tmp/go-build731085030/github.com/blakesmith/go-grok/_obj/grok.cgo2.o: In function `_cgo_4244208c3352_Cfunc_grok_discover_new':
../../blakesmith/go-grok/grok.go:68: undefined reference to `grok_discover_new'
/tmp/go-build731085030/github.com/blakesmith/go-grok/_obj/grok.cgo2.o: In function `_cgo_4244208c3352_Cfunc_grok_compile':
../../blakesmith/go-grok/grok.go:46: undefined reference to `grok_compile'
/tmp/go-build731085030/github.com/blakesmith/go-grok/_obj/grok.cgo2.o: In function `_cgo_4244208c3352_Cfunc_grok_match_walk_init':
../../blakesmith/go-grok/grok.go:108: undefined reference to `grok_match_walk_init'
/tmp/go-build731085030/github.com/blakesmith/go-grok/_obj/grok.cgo2.o: In function `_cgo_4244208c3352_Cfunc_grok_match_walk_end':
../../blakesmith/go-grok/grok.go:99: undefined reference to `grok_match_walk_end'
/tmp/go-build731085030/github.com/blakesmith/go-grok/_obj/grok.cgo2.o: In function `_cgo_4244208c3352_Cfunc_grok_free':
../../blakesmith/go-grok/grok.go:90: undefined reference to `grok_free'
/tmp/go-build731085030/github.com/blakesmith/go-grok/_obj/grok.cgo2.o: In function `_cgo_4244208c3352_Cfunc_grok_discover':
../../blakesmith/go-grok/grok.go:58: undefined reference to `grok_discover'
/tmp/go-build731085030/github.com/blakesmith/go-grok/_obj/grok.cgo2.o: In function `_cgo_4244208c3352_Cfunc_free':
../../blakesmith/go-grok/grok.go:34: undefined reference to `free'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If I then just try to build it normally I also get the same things:

```
[mm17@mm17 grogger]$ go build grogger.go
# github.com/blakesmith/go-grok
/usr/bin/ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000000400180
/tmp/go-build294631148/github.com/blakesmith/go-grok/_obj/grok.cgo2.o: In function `_cgo_4244208c3352_Cfunc_strlen':
../../blakesmith/go-grok/grok.go:169: undefined reference to `strlen'
....
```

I'm sure I'm just doing something stupid, but I can't seem to figure it out, I'm pretty novice when it comes to gcc and go, this is my first non toy program.

Comment: Does adding `-lc` to `LDFLAGS` help? `#cgo LDFLAGS: -L /usr/lib/libgrok.so -lgrok -lc`?

Comment: Nope, still the same results

Comment: Do you have libgrok.a in your library path?  You can't make a static executable from shared libraries.

Comment: No, I take it I'll need to get all the libraries statically compiled.

Comment: Also, the argument to `-L` should be a directory containing libraries rather than the file name of an individual library. (not that this is likely to help if you don't have static libraries available)

Answer (score 0):

When you compile native library with GCC make sure to use -fPIC option.

If library is compiled without -fPIC GO will not be able to locate functions in it.